# Scroll to div on page load while using pjax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, pjax

So i'm using pjax so when a user clicks a link instead of loading a new page it will drag the content in. The content has a navigation bar at the top with the content underneath. Upon click the navigation bar it hides and displays certain contents.. that is working fine.

My problem. When the content is dragged in, I want the page to scroll straight to the navigation bar instead of sticking at the top of the page and the user needs to scroll to it. I've used:

```
$(function() {
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#in-page-nav').offset().top}, 1000);
});
```

To scroll to the div on the page load, and it works fine when I refresh the page. But doesn't work when pjax pulls the content into the page.

Any help i'd be really grateful, thank you!

Comment: you may be getting some error in console. can you check and tell me

Comment: If you are doing it on document ready like your code snippet suggests, then I am guessing the id that you are trying to scroll to doesn't exist yet if pjax is pulling it in. You need to defer the animation until after pjax loads that part of the page.

Comment: Thanks Tim, thats exactly what was happening. I debated whether or not to put a delay on the scroll function. But thats not brilliant incase the webpage loads slow. Therefore, my below answer fixed my issue I check the pjax documentation and added a success callback on the pjax.connect function which worked :)

Comment: @Charles that's essentially what I would have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED**

Okay so I'm not sure if anyone has/had this problem but just for reference sake and if anyone comes across this problem heres what I did:

I looked at pjax documentation;

complete - When AJAX request has completed
success - When AJAX request has completed successfully

are two of the callbacks which can be used.

```
pjax.connect({
    'success': function(e){
        window.location.hash = $('#in-page-nav a').eq(0).attr('href');
        // $(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#in-page-nav').offset().top}, 1000);
        },
});
```

So my previous code which animate scroll to a div on page load copied that and placed this within the pjax.connent and used the success callback. This works perfectly. I kept the code to animate on page load as well so if a user bookmarks the link or sends it and uses the link directly. Then the page will load the same.

Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 3):

You could do your animation in the `pjax:success` event.  `pjax:success` is fired:

> after replacing HTML content loaded from the server

**Example**

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function() {
  // Your scroll animation here.
})
```

See [Pjax events](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events) for more details.